# Need to create a code validating editor like in codecademy/w3schools

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

how to create a code editor in a web page(SPA - like angular) that validates user input code like in codecademy/w3schools

Comment: Just use codemirror or ace editor

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would start experimenting with, if I had to do something like this. You can split the view in 2 panels:

- left panel: the editor where the user enters code
- right panel: an iframe where you serve the content that is written by the user. You can generate the iframe on the go (as user types) or you can serve it by using a url of your domain on Submit button (you save the user input to a html file, including styling etc) and then you serve the iframe.

How does this sound ?

Comment: how about to have fixed output?

Comment: If by fixed output you mean that the user should only update certain things (for example he has to add a class to a h1 tag element), then you can search for that change inside its input and if it's found, you add that to the live preview (right panel). You also ignore other changes the user might have done if you only want displayed what you expect at that step of the tutorial. Does this answer your question?

Comment: For HTML, it's good... but I need to do it with oops languages like checking the function, anyhow I can also check only the output but I need to know is there any library available to do that ? or should I manually do that?

Comment: and also how can I execute different language like c/c++ on the preview iframe?

Comment: I don't really know any library, sorry. But it should definitely be something useful out there! Depends on the programming language you choose to implement in. For example using PHP you can send the user input and execute server side and validate it and then manage the response using javascript.

Comment: If this was helpful you might consider accepting as an answer. Thanks!